# Assign/Join value from dataframe col `C` corresponding to same pair of values `A` & `B` to a second dataframe. R - dplyr

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have two dataframes.

- The first (`df1`) one is a frequency dataframe of coocuring strings `names1` and `names2` and their `frequency`.
- The second (`df2`) one contains two columns `names1` and `names2` containing one or many times or not of those pairs. And sometimes in a different order.

I want to assignate the frequency in a new column from the **first dafarame `df1`**,

```
df1 <- tibble(names1 = c('architecture', 'assessment', 'build'), 
              names2 = c('build', 'data', 'data'),
              frequency = c(36,13,720))

# A tibble: 3 x 3
  names1       names2 frequency
  <chr>        <chr>      <dbl>
1 architecture build         36
2 assessment   data          13
3 build        data          720
```

in the **second dataframe `df2`**.

```
df2 <- tibble(names1 = c('architecture', 'build', 'assessment','assessment', 'business'), 
              names2 = c('build','architecture', 'data', 'data', 'strategy'))

  names1       names2        
  <chr>        <chr>         
1 architecture build         
2 build        architecture  
3 assessment   data          
4 assessment   data   
5 business     strategy
```

For this result:

```
  names1       names2        frequency
  <chr>        <chr>         <dbl>
1 architecture build         36
2 build        architecture  36
3 assessment   data          13
4 assessment   data          13
5 business     strategy      0
```

NB: Sometimes I have `df1$names1 == df2$names1  && df1$names2 == df2$names2` **or** `df1$names1 == df2$names2  && df1$names2 == df2$names1`

```
1 architecture build         36
2 build        architecture  36
```

NB: I want to keep the rows with no matching

```
5 business     strategy      0
```

Comment: Check out `left_join` and `right_join` from `dplyr`

Comment: my issue is that  sometimes I have `df1$A == df2$B  && df1$B == df2$A` **or** `df1$A == df2$B  && df1$B == df2$A`
```
1 architecture build         36
2 build        architecture  36
```

Answer (score 2):

The issue here is that order of the names columns is important in order to join, so you have to update your datasets and apply a consistent order.

Here's a `dplyr` solution:

```
library(dplyr)

df1 <- tibble(names1 = c('architecture', 'assessment', 'build'), 
              names2 = c('build', 'data', 'data'),
              frequency = c(36,13,720))

df2 <- tibble(names1 = c('architecture', 'build', 'assessment','assessment', 'business'), 
              names2 = c('build','architecture', 'data', 'data', 'strategy'))

# update df1
df1 = df1 %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(names = paste0(sort(c(names1, names2)), collapse = "_")) %>% 
  select(names, frequency)

# update df2
df2 = df2 %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(names = paste0(sort(c(names1, names2)), collapse = "_"))

# join datasets and update columns
left_join(df2, df1, by="names") %>%
  mutate(frequency = coalesce(frequency, 0)) %>%
  select(-names) %>%
  ungroup()

#   names1       names2       frequency
#   <chr>        <chr>            <dbl>
# 1 architecture build               36
# 2 build        architecture        36
# 3 assessment   data                13
# 4 assessment   data                13
# 5 business     strategy             0
```

Answer (score 2):

A recursive `tidyr::left_join` with some `dplyr` solution:

```
require(dplyr
require(tidyr) 
left_join(df2,df1,by=c("names1","names2")) %>% 
   left_join(df1,by=c(names1="names2",names2="names1")) %>% 
   mutate(frequency=coalesce(frequency.x,frequency.y,0)) %>% 
   select(-frequency.x,-frequency.y)
```

This solution retains the orders of the columns in df2. The mutate and select lines are there because left_join adds new columns, which need to be combined back into a single frequency column (and replace NAs with 0) and then removed.

Result:

```
# A tibble: 5 x 3
  names1       names2       frequency
  <chr>        <chr>            <dbl>
1 architecture build               36
2 build        architecture        36
3 assessment   data                13
4 assessment   data                13
5 business     strategy             0
```